# 5-fold cross validation in R: getting error Age variable different lengths

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-science-model, cross-validation

I am tasked to do a 5-fold cross validation for my R grad course with pga golf data. I continually get an error for a certain variable, Age, saying different lengths. Here is the error code:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = form, data = data[rows.in, ], drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Age')
```

Here is the model I am working with:

```
model1 <- lm(pga$log_avg_winnings ~ Age + AverageDrive + DrivingAccuracy + GreensonRegulation + AverageNumofPutts + SavePercent + NumEvents, data=pga)
```

Here is the k-fold code that brings up the error above:

```
KCV=cv.lm(data=pga, model1, m=5, seed=0)
```

Does anyone know why this is? I have troubleshooted and cannot figure this out. It has the same # of records as the other variables. There are zero missing values.

Age is an integer. Here is Age's data, looks good:

```
pga$Age [1] 23 24 34 34 31 29 42 28 27 47 40 38 46 29 36 38 45 43 34 36 35 31 33 33 32 34 27 39 30 25 [31] 31 36 31 35 36 45 32 36 38 37 28 46 37 30 44 34 36 35 45 25 35 44 37 40 34 37 42 35 36 42 [61] 35 42 35 45 48 30 42 27 39 40 31 40 29 33 30 33 33 22 29 44 39 31 27 44 51 37 41 40 47 38 [91] 39 40 30 46 47 38 43 41 29 33 26 34 41 38 32 24 34 35 44 37 28 21 40 42 31 40 37 49 25 27 [121] 43 44 33 47 30 34 33 26 45 37 34 42 47 32 32 45 36 35 28 35 44 37 34 35 29 34 28 33 32 36 [151] 41 35 29 27 28 46 28 31 49 39 49 40 24 35 35 40 36 40 35 31 42 37 44 43 37 31 33 30 31 28 [181] 28 34 38 35 39 44 36 45 45 45 38 36 28 41 40 28
```

You can see here Age has an integer datatype, similar to a couple of the other datatypes and the Age variable has the same # of records (196) as the other records. What am I doing wrong?

```
str(pga)

'data.frame':   196 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Age               : int  23 24 34 34 31 29 42 28 27 47 ...
 $ AverageDrive      : num  288 295 286 298 289 ...
 $ DrivingAccuracy   : num  53.1 57.7 64.2 59 60.5 68.8 74.2 64.4 64.3 62.6 ...
 $ GreensonRegulation: num  58.2 65.6 63.8 63 62.5 67 68.9 64.2 63.4 65.3 ...
 $ AverageNumofPutts : num  1.77 1.76 1.79 1.79 1.77 ...
 $ SavePercent       : num  50.9 59.3 50.7 47.7 43.5 50.9 40.4 53.8 42.2 47.7 ...
 $ NumEvents         : int  27 16 24 20 30 23 23 27 20 15 ...
 $ AverageWinnings   : int  23440 232812 54729 40419 16202 58932 41833 38406 25041 62906 ...
 $ log_avg_winnings  : num  10.06 12.36 10.91 10.61 9.69 ...
```